# Twitter shortens my already shortened URLs. Will this affect my bitly statistics?

Tags: twitter, bit.ly

For some time now, I've happily been using bitly with a custom domain to shorten URLs on Twitter, but recently Twitter has decided to start shortening my already shortened URLs.

Will this affect my statistics on bitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes<sup>*</sup>, it will. Consider [this tweet of mine](https://twitter.com/#!/SathyaBhat/status/136769375045824512) which was shortened to ( http://u.sbhat.me/rwa550 ) & which twitter wrapped with the t.co URL ( http://t.co/X3V8Hhsp ) & posted to my timeline.

[Checking on the stats](https://bitly.com/rwa550+) confirmed that the referrer was t.co.

[image]

**I believe, the reason there are couple of twitter.com & hootsuite.com referrers comes down to the way clients handle the API - twitter API provides both the t.co & the "long" URL(in this case, the shortened URL). If the client shows & sends request directly to the long URL, the obviously, the referrer won't be altered. However, twitter webpage shows the *long* URL but is actually linked to the *short* one and hence the referrer remains the short, i.e., t.co one.*

Comment: Looks like we came to the same conclusion. Funny that you should answer this question, since I learned about bitly custom domains because of yours... :-)